# Which is more efficient, importing or pass as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very curious to know which of these two methods is more efficient and why,
I have a parent component that contains different child components and imported `currentUser` in the parent component in order to check if the user is an admin, I also need to do that type of checking inside each of the child components, which one is better in terms of performance, to import the `currentUser` from the store in each child components or to pass it as props to each of them?

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
import AnotherChildComponent from "./AnotherChildComponent";
import DifferentChildComponent from "./DifferentChildComponent";
import {currentUser} from "../../stores/RootStore;

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
   const {isAdmin} = currentUser();
   return (
    <div>
     {isAdmin && (
       <h1>Admin</h1>
      )
     }
     <ChildComponent />
     <AnotherChildComponent />
     <DifferentChildComponent />
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: Would the components properly update themselves if you did it the first way, importing them individually in each file?

Comment: What kind of store do you use?

Comment: @TKoL Yes, they would.

Comment: Importing a constant is more performant than passing it through React's machinery, but importing doesn't allow simple injection of different values (like mocks in testing).

Comment: @bapafes482 MobX store

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a matter of efficiency, there isn't any significant difference which of those ways you use in terms of efficiency.

It's a matter of:

- Responsibility - is the parent component responsible for the current user information, or is the module exporting the `currentUser` function responsible for that?
- Complexity and coupling - if you decided that having the module exporting `currentUser` being the responsible party is best, then:

  - Is the complexity of passing the information between components worth it?
  - Persumably the current user can change. Is it worth complexity to all the dependent components to handle the curent user changing rather than simply driving them with a prop?
- Testability - [as Bergi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665026/which-is-more-efficient-importing-or-pass-as-props/59665187#comment105489111_59665026), if it's a prop it's easier to pass different values to individual components in tests.

Only you and your team can answer those questions, but those are the ones I'd be asking, rather than efficiency. A single function call vs. a prop is not worth worrying about from an efficiency standpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the info, passing the information between the different components seems not to really worth it, which was why I was curious in the first place if importing it individually has any effect.

Comment: Answers like this are helpful, but do not answer the question.  "there isn't any significant difference" - This means there is a still a difference, so what is that difference?  "It's not a matter of efficiency" - This redirects the question.  The question asks which is better in terms of performance.   Again, these kind of responses are GREAT info, but do not actually provide the answer to the question.  I recommend adding that in!